# Retrieving data from a database

Tags: php

I have a database named products,and i want to retrieve data from the database  using php, i have never done php . am a beginer,i have tried using the information from other answers in this forums but am still stuck.any help is appreciated

I have used Nemanja Adamov's code and it worked well.

Comment: Can you give examples of the code you have already tried?

Comment: You don't understand Stack Overflow answers and decided to ask for more?

Comment: This is the code
 
<?php
include "products.db";

error_reporting(0),

$link_db=db_connect(products);

if(!link_db){

die (sql_error());
else{

echo "the connection occured";
}

$sql="SELECT * FROM products

where ItemName,ItemId IN";

foreach($_POST ['ItemName'],$POST['ItemId']) as $product

$sql="'.$products.',";

$sql=substr($sql,0,-1).")";

$result=mysql_fetch_array($result))

{
print$row['ItemName'], $row[ItemId];
}

?>

Comment: Alvaro,i have tried to replicate what i have found on an answer but i did not get the output,i dont know where am goin wrong in this.

Comment: @user3881523 - firstly, please edit your question to include your code. Secondly, you need to explain what problem you're having. Do you get an error message? A blank screen? What happens when you run your code? What is supposed to happen? Do you have a `products` table in your database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the code to connect with database, and fetching the results:
1. DB connection.

```
<?php
    $host = "localhost";
    $username = "your_username";
    $password = "your_password";
    $db_name = "your_db_name";
    $connection = mysql_connect( $host, $username, $password ) or die ( "Error:: [1]" );
    mysql_select_db( $db_name, $connection ) or die ( "Error:: [2]" );
?>
```

Wrapp above code  in "db_conn.inc", and later if you want something to do with database ( update/insert/read ), just do the *include 'db_conn.inc';*
2. Fetching results.

```
<?php
    include( 'db_conn.inc' );
    $query = "select `id`,`name` from `mytable`"; //query...
    $result = mysql_query( $query, $connection ); //make query request
    if ( $result ) { //if  result has any results
        print '<table>
                <tr>
                    <td>ID</td>
                    <td>Name</td>
                </tr>';
        while ( $row = mysql_fetch_array( $result ) ) {
        print '<tr>
                    <td>' . $row[0] . '</td>
                    <td>' . $row[1] . '</td>
               </tr>';
        }
    }
        print '</table>';

    mysql_close($connection); //close connection
?>
```

Feel free to upvote / set this answer as accepted if it solved your problem.

Comment: This is what am getting

ID Name';while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)) {print''.$row[0].''row[1].'';}}
print'';mysql_close($connection);

Comment: Did you have <?php ?> in both files; in *index.php* and *db_conn.inc*? This code is tested and working.

Comment: Thanx Adamov,have seen my mistake now,i appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

If you use MySQL, i recommend you to use  [mysqli_*](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php)

By the way, take a look on [PDO](http://php.net/manual/ru/book.pdo.php)

Good luck!